# $request->route() is null in Middleware, how can I filter by route parameters?

Tags: laravel

Laravel 5.1 deprecates `Route::filter()` and other related functions, [claiming in the docs that](http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade):

> Route filters have been deprecated in preference of middleware.

But if your route filter accesses route parameters, how can you replace this with middleware, since the `$request->route()` is `null` in middleware?

```
Route::filter('foo', function($route, $request) {
    if ($route->parameter('bar') > 1000) {
         return Redirect::route('large-bars');
    }
});
```

The closest I can see is something like

```
class FooMiddleware {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Note that $request->route() is null here, as the request
        // hasn't been handled by Laravel yet.

        if ($request->segment(4) > 1000) { // ewww...
            return Redirect::route('large-bars');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

but this is obviously much more brittle than referring to the parameter by name. What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`$request->route()` is only null for global middleware registered in `App\Http\Kernel::$middleware`. To have access to the current route, instead you must register your middleware in `Kernel::$routeMiddleware`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...,
    'foo' => FooMiddleware::class,
];
```

[Proposals to change this behavior have been rejected by the Laravel maintainers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/9708) due to architectural concerns.

Comment: By the other solution the middleware will be called automatically in every request. So, how can I start that middleware by this solution? I mean how can be accessed?

Comment: @Ben Thank you, you saved me 3 hours of debugging.