# Laravel - forgetParameter

Tags: laravel, routes

My project is multi language, so in most route I add parameter "locale". But latter I do not need to pass "locale" parameter to my controllers. I try to remove this parameter using **forgetParameter()** method but when I use this method then I have error "**Route not bound**".

So what I'm doing wrong.

How to remove "locale" from all routes?

**Laravel 5.8**

My route file.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}','where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']], function() {

Auth::routes([app()->getLocale()]);
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('mainPage');


Route::get('/user/{id}','UserController@showUser')->name('getUserProfile')->forgetParameter('locale');
Route::get('/user/{id}/edit','UserController@editUser')->name('editUserProfile')
    ->middleware('can:editUser,App\User,id')->forgetParameter('locale');
Route::patch('/user/{id}/edit','UserController@updateUser')->name('updateUserProfile')
    ->middleware('can:updateUser,App\User,id')->forgetParameter('locale');

});
```

It's not duplicate with this question - [Laravel 5.4: How to DO NOT use route parameter in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619512/laravel-5-4-how-to-do-not-use-route-parameter-in-controller)

Solution in that question doesn't work in my case. And my question is why "forgotParamter()" throw an error?

Other question is, why I can't use this construction in middleware:

```
$request->route()->forgetParameter('locale')
```

I have following error:

> Call to a member function is() on null

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4: How to DO NOT use route parameter in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619512/laravel-5-4-how-to-do-not-use-route-parameter-in-controller)

Comment: I had a similar issue. Is it possible that you're attempting to use a global middleware? According to this,[$request->route() is null in Middleware, how can I filter by route parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868759/request-route-is-null-in-middleware-how-can-i-filter-by-route-parameters) the route can't be accessed in globals, so you would need to register it as a route middleware.

Answer (score 1):

Try to forget the parameter in an inline middleware in the controller's constructor. Actually, I would  use a base controller: 1, get the route value; 2, set to a protected property, so inherited controllers can access to the value; 3, forget the parameter.

```php
<?php
// Localized/Controller.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Localized;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as ControllerBase;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Controller extends ControllerBase
{
    protected string $currentLocale;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            // If you need to access this later on inherited controllers
            $this->currentLocale = $request->route('locale') ?? 'en';

            // Other operations, like setting the locale or check if lang is available, etc
 
            $request->route()->forgetParameter('locale');

            return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
// Localized/UserController.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Localized;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// Extends the our base controller instead of App\Http\Controllers\Controller
class UserController extends Controller 
{
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        // No need of string $locale arg
        dd($this->currentLocale);
    }

}
```